# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #134: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

I am using AdMob in my main application. But when i start some service i get exception: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #134: Error inflating class <unknown>`

`main` AdMob layout

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="xxx"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and then when i run service which call this code:

```
private View getMainLayout() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

        return layout;
    }
```

i get exception:

```
01-26 07:55:56.500: W/dalvikvm(21075): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c7a1f8)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.xxx.sss.service.SmsService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #134: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2274)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #134: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at com.xxx.sss.service.SmsService.getMainLayout(SmsService.java:79)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at com.xxx.sss.service.SmsService.setOnLabelOnButton(SmsService.java:68)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at com.xxx.sss.service.SmsService.onCreate(SmsService.java:37)
01-26 07:55:56.655: E/AndroidRuntime(21075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2264)
```

what is wrong?

Comment: can you point out line 134 in xml?

Comment: line 134 is <com.google.ads.AdView

Comment: yes it is. Library is added in libs folder

Comment: I'm seeing the same, but only for a very small section of the users. None of them seems to be rooted, but still suspect some ad-blocking modification on their part.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this 
add dependency: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.+'
to your app level build.gradel and build the project.

and then in your layout.xml file add

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
```

banner_ad_unit_id: this must be your unique id

add bellow line to your java file java file

```
mAdView = (AdView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

do not forget to add **AdActivity** in a manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to declare `com.google.ads.AdView` library in manifest file?

Comment: this i have in my <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>